# Adding Line to Google combo chart

Tags: php, sql, charts, google-visualization

I have a combo chart display employee names on the x axis and number of holiday days they have taken , I want to add in a line to the chart to diaplay the max holiday days they can take which is 20. How do i manually add this into the chart 
Below is my code

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

  function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Employee', 'Holiday Days Taken'],
       <?php 
     while($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
     {
        echo "['".$row["name"]."',".$row["Holidays_taken"]."],"; 
     }
     ?>
                 
                    ]);
                       data.addColumn('number', 'Average');
                        data.addRows([
    [null, null, 20]
    
]);
                 

    var options = {
      title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
      vAxis: {title: 'No. of Holidays Taken'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Employee'},
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {5: {type: 'line'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to add a line to the combo chart,
add another column to the data table for the max.
then add the max value to each row...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Employee', 'Holiday Days Taken', 'Max'],
  ['Jim', 5, 12],
  ['Bob', 3, 12],
  ['Tom', 6, 12],
]);
```

in the chart options, change the series type for max to line.
the series number is the zero-based index of the y-axis column in the data table.
in this case, there are two y-axis columns,
so the series number is 1...

```
series: {1: {type: 'line'}}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Employee', 'Holiday Days Taken', 'Max'],
    ['Jim', 5, 12],
    ['Bob', 3, 12],
    ['Tom', 6, 12],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    vAxis: {title: 'No. of Holidays Taken'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Employee'},
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {1: {type: 'line'}}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```